# Логирование изменений в БД

Tags: yii, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть задача: сохранять удаления и обновления записей во всех таблицах. Проект написан на yii. СУБД: mysql. Имеется 8 таблиц. Содержание одного лога:

[удалена/обновлена] запись в таблице [имя_таблицы] со значениями (бывшими) [имя_поля:значение, ...]. Автор изменений: [id_user]

Какие решения можете предложить?

Вот, что мне приходит в голову:
 1. Триггеры. Но отпадают, т.к. не смогу получить кто автор изменений, т.е. кто авторизован - авторизация хранится в сессии.
 2. Преподу так и не удалось доказать, что это можно сделать через ежедневные бэкапы БД и включить логирование всех запросов к БД для отслеживания чего творилось с ней. Так что отпадает.
 3. Вроде самый логичный пока - повесить бихейверы на модели yii. В них генерировать нужную строку и записывать эту строку в таблицу БД.
 4. Просто в каждом месте кода, где что-либо удаляется или обновляется записывать лог. ИМХО, некрасивый вариант.

Цель: естественно, минимальные телодвижения и ковыряния кода)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 вариант вполне подходящий

Comment: @Ale_x, я так и думал, но т.к. являюсь новичком yii, php и mysql, то думал может я чего-то не знаю и кто-то предложит более изящные и простые варианты.

Comment: Почитал про behavoir в yii и возник вопрос. Если для обновления и вставки записи используется метод save(), как написать behavoir именно к обновлению, а не к добавлению записи? Или никак?  
П.С. Задал отдельным вопросом. См. у меня в профиле.